# Kapt Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, annotation-processor

I'm trying to develop a Kotlin AnnotationProcessor library, and I can't figure why I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>   > Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - compiler.jar (project :compiler)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

I know that as mentionned I could use `includeCompileClasspath  = true` and I tried it and it works fine. But as mentionned, it's deprecated, soon removed, and it is expected to be used for libraries you don't use according to android doc.

So I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

### App module

**Hello.kt**

```
@HelloGenerated
class Hello(){
    override fun showLog() {
        Log.i(Hello::class.simpleName, "${Gahfy_Hello().getName()}")
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle**

dependencies{
        kapt project(":compiler")
        compileOnly project(":compiler")
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

### Compiler module

**HelloGenerated.kt**

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class HelloGenerated
```

*I also tried without Target and Retention and have same issue*

**HelloGenerator.kt**

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("net.gahfy.HelloGenerated")
class HelloGeneratedInjectorProcessor: AbstractProcessor() {

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): MutableSet<String> {
        return mutableSetOf(HelloGenerated::class.java.name)
    }

    override fun getSupportedSourceVersion(): SourceVersion {
        return SourceVersion.latest()
    }

    override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
        val annotation = annotations.firstOrNull { it.toString() == "net.gahfy.HelloGenerated" } ?: return false
        for (element in roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation)) {
            val className = element.simpleName.toString()
            val `package` = processingEnv.elementUtils.getPackageOf(element).toString()
            generateClass(className, `package`)
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun generateClass(className: String, `package`: String) {
        val kotlinGeneratedPath = (processingEnv.options["kapt.kotlin.generated"] as String).replace("kaptKotlin", "kapt")
        val kaptKotlinGenerated = File(kotlinGeneratedPath)
        val source = "package $`package`\n\nclass Lachazette_$className(){fun getName():String{return \"World\"}}"
        val relativePath = `package`.replace('.', File.separatorChar)

        val folder = File(kaptKotlinGenerated, relativePath).apply { if(!exists()){mkdirs()} }
        File(folder, "Lachazette_$className.kt").writeText(source)
    }

    companion object {
        const val KAPT_KOTLIN_GENERATED_OPTION_NAME = "kapt.kotlin.generated"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

**resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
net.gahfy.HelloGenerator
```

I'm now looking for a cleaner solution than just `includeCompileClasspath  = true`.

Some information:

- kapt works well, I'm using it with Dagger and BindingAdapter without any problem
- My annotation processor is well processed when building, and the message in the log is the good one when I set `includeCompileClasspath  = true`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is 100% related to your problem but I had the same error after moving auto-value to `kapt`. I solved it by declaring the auto-value dependency as both `kapt` **and** `annotationProcessor`.

So in your case:

```
dependencies{
    kapt project(":compiler")
    annotationProcessor project(":compiler")
    compileOnly project(":compiler")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Looks like you also commented with this on the issue in the jetbrains repo: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/issues/59
It works for me too but the seems like a workaround for a bug in AS 3 or Gradle?

Comment: Indeed. Haven't found a better solution yet, unfortunately

Comment: I've logged a bug now in Android bug tracker for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80270236